# How to list callers of a function in Elixir?

Tags: debugging, elixir

I'm refactoring a function and I want to know every file that calls it. With aliases and imports, a simple grep would list other functions with the same name in different modules or would miss some calls.

I tried using `mix xref` but it doesn't work with functions, only modules (I'm using Elixir 1.12.1).

```
$ mix xref callers MySchema.changeset/2
** (Mix) xref callers MODULE expects a MODULE, got: MySchema.changeset/2
```

Is there a tool or a xref command to list callers of a function in Elixir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a deprecated [`Mix.Tasks.Xref.calls/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Xref.html#calls/1) function, but it has been deprecated for a reason, [Compilation tracers](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#module-compilation-tracers) are way more powerful.

You might set a tracer for `{:remote_function, _, YourModule, :your_fun, your_arity}` and simply `IO.puts/2` from there.